# Ansible working with multiple loops in conditions

Tags: ansible

how can I add a condition to ansible task that is based on a loop, when the task itself also based on a loop?

For example, here's my code:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    current_version: 826
    versions:
      - 805
      - 821
      - 824
      - 826
  tasks:
    - name: First Task
      find:
          paths: /Users/tomer/projects/personal/ansible/test
          patterns: snapshot* 
      register: files
      when:
        - current_version == item
      loop: "{{versions}}"

    - name: Second task
      set_fact:
        test_work:  "{{ true if item > 0 else false}}"
      loop:
        -  "{{ files | json_query('results[*].matched') }}"
```

So far, this is working as expected.
The first task is looking for any file with the name `snapshot` if the `current_version` is matching one of the versions in the list.

The second task iterates over the dictionary result from the first task and based on each item it is setting the fact. (In my case, only one item has this attribute).

I wanted to run the second task, *only* when the first task *did* run, however, the *changed* status is always `false`, so this condition is not useful.
I wanted to add the same condition of `current_version` == `item` but I can't use `item` twice here.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find command is not really going to [change anything](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#changed), it just queries the file system without doing any modification, so it will indeed always give you a `false`.

On the other hand, you can definitely use the `skipped` field of the `item`.

This said, I would simplify the loop on your `set_fact`, because there is no real need to use `json_query` here.

This task would do the job perfectly fine:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    test_work: "{{ item.matched > 0 }}"
  loop: "{{ files.results }}"
  when: item is not skipped
```

---

Another extra tip is to not do things like

```
true if condition_that_evaluates_to_true else false
```

But rather do right away

```
condition_that_evaluates_to_true
```

---

Here would be a made up example playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
      
  tasks:
    - find:
        path: /tmp
        pattern: dummy*
      when: item == current_version
      register: files
      loop: "{{ versions }}"
      vars:
        current_version: 826
        versions:
          - 805
          - 821
          - 824
          - 826

    - debug:
        msg:  "{{ item.matched > 0 }}"
      loop: "{{ files.results }}"
      when: item is not skipped
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
```

This would yield the result

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [find] ******************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=805) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=821) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=824) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=826)

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=805) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=821) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=824) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=826) => {
    "msg": true
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the anser.
Here's what I've done:   

  - set_fact:
        test_work: "{{ item.matched > 0 }}"
      loop:
        -  "{{ files.results }}"


It resulted in this error:
`The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'matched`

Comment: Mind at how I created my loop: `loop: "{{ files.results }}"` by doing it the way you are, you are actually creating a list of list, which is causing you this error.